# Need to convert parameter into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code bellow.

```
.attr("onclick", "Display(\"Do you wish to do this?\",null," + Test.toggle + ",\"" + [Test.Comment,Test.Valid == "True"] + "\");")
```

Which is good, it calls a function called `Test.toggle(Test.Comment,Test.Valid);`

Problem is that in **Test.toggle()** I'm using the  **.apply()** function, and it expects an array and not arguments (which **.call()**) does. I can't change the function **Test.toggle()** so it starts using **.call()** so I must supply an array of objects instead.

I.E the function call must look like `Test.toggle([Test.Comment,Test.Valid]);`

instead.

How can I do this?

I tried things like

```
.attr("onclick", "AlertBox(\"Do you wish to do this valid thing?\",null," + EpgTest.toggleValid + ",\"[" + [data.Id + "," + data.Valid == "True"] + "]\");")
```

That is adding additional "[" signs outside but it didn't work. Can you guys please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why use `onclick` for this and not put it into a jQuery click handler instead?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a wrapper function for `Test.toggle` that takes non-array parameters and passes them into `toggle`, like so:

```
Test.wrappedToggle = function(a,b){ return Test.toggle([a,b]); };
```

You can then use `wrappedToggle` in place of toggle when calling it inline.